# Global new operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I have read about `new` and `delete` overloading for memory tracking in [How_To_Find_Memory_Leaks](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/How_To_Find_Memory_Leaks.shtml)

I defined these global operators:

```
inline void* __cdecl operator new( unsigned int size, const char *file, int line ) {
    void* ptr = malloc( size );
    AddTrack((DWORD)ptr, size, file, line);
    return ptr;

}

inline void* __cdecl operator new( unsigned int size, void* ptr, const char *file, int line ) {
    return ptr;
}
```

It works well with new and new[] operators, but i have a problem with placement new ( second one ). My define look like:

```
#define new new( __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new(x) new( x, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

They work separately. But when i try to use them both there are errors appear. As I understand they substitute each other. I know I can have macro with variable number of arguments like this:

```
#define new( ... ) new( __VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

But I need the same macro with and without arguments at all, so both `new`-s in these lines substitute right:

```
g_brushes = new Brush[ num_brushes ];
...
new( &g_brushes[i] )Brush(sides);
```

Comment: have you considered using a profiler ? Why you want to "track" memory like that ?

Comment: You cannot have two macros with the same name, and a macro must be either an object-like macro, or a function-like macro, you cannot have both. The preprocessor doesn't see `new` as a keyword, it sees it as an identifier like any other, so anything that lets you replace `new` in `new T()` will also replace `new` in `new(something) T()` the same way.

Comment: Because, as i understood, this method work in any compiler.

Comment: flipcode! Oh the memories! Anyway, placement-new is dangerous, and should not really be used. It leads to object-slicing, and is almost impossible to diagnose. See [GotW #22: Object Lifetimes - Part I](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/022.htm) for more information. - And don't forget to visit the [flipcode Image of the Day gallery](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/iotd.shtml)!

Comment: Rather than rolling your own, use an already developed leak detection tool such as `valgrind`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you decide to walk the dark path of overriding the global new, you have to make sure you consider all of the following scenarios:

```
new Foo;                            // 1
new Foo[10];                        // 2
new (std::nothrow) Foo;             // 3
new (p) Foo;                        // 4 - placement, not overridable
(Foo*) ::operator new(sizeof(Foo)); // 5 - direct invocation of the operator
```

And it should be possible to be able to handle all the above except for the last. Shudder.

**The necessary knol and the sleight of hand is that your macro should end with `new`**. When your macro ends with `new`, you can delegate the different ways it can be invoked to `new` itself.

Here's one, non-thread safe way to proceed. Define a type to capture the context of the invocation, so we will be able to retrieve this context later in the operator itself,

```
struct new_context {
    new_context(const char* file, const int line)
        : file_(file), line_(line) { scope_ = this; }
    ~new_context() { scope_ = 0; }

    static new_context const& scope() { assert(scope_); return *scope_; }

    operator bool() const { return false; }

    const char* file_;
    const int line_;
private:
    static new_context* scope_;
};
```

Next, define your override to create a `new_context` temporary just before the invocation,

```
#define new new_context(__FILE__, __LINE__) ? 0 : new
```

using the ternary operator conditional assignment to evaluate an expression before delegating to the operator new, notice that it is where the `operator bool` that we have defined above comes handy.

Then inside your new overrides (I'll use standard C++98 here instead of the MSC C++), all you have to do is to retrieve the context:

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) {
    std::cout 
        << "new" 
        << "," << new_context::scope().file_ 
        << ":" << new_context::scope().line_ 
        << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This approach will deal with all the cases `1-4` from above, and what's important and can be easily overlooked is that in case `4` where your overloads are not invoked, as you **cannot replace placement new (§18.4.​1.3)**, you still know that placement new took place because `new_context` will be created and destroyed.

---

To summarise, you don’t need to modify what follows after the `new` operator, so all possible syntaxes remain valid. And the other point is that the `new_context` object temporary is going to be kept alive until the end of the expression the operator participates in, so you are safe to obtain it from a global singleton.

---

**[See a gcc example live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f34fd184cfffd69)**. *Adapting to MSC is left to the reader.*