# Problems related to overriding global new and delete operators

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, stl, new-operator

Sometime ago I saw a post about problems related to globally overriding new and delete operators. Post was saying that it could cause problems with STL and many other libraries.

Now I am writing a memory manager. I am considering overriding the **global** new and delete operators for optimizing the whole application. Inside the custom memory manager, the same old new and delete operators are used (to allocate large chunks of memory as required at run-time, while allocating portions of them for actual use in my software).

- Could I be having any problems with this approach? I wish to use many libraries in my application such as DirectX, STL and Boost.
- Could those rumors which I mentioned at 1st paragraph, be true?

I'm using VS2010

-- EDIT --

I should be using malloc() and free() inside the MemoryManager rite.

Comment: Another way of overriding part of the memory allocation subsystem is to write an allocator that you provide to all containers.

Comment: You should consider having a read on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22039345/1413395

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to override global new/delete, it is better using well tested and performant libraries:

- [TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)
- [NedMalloc](http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedmalloc/)

The reason is that those libraries will be better in the general case than anything you can write (less bugs, more performance etc).
If you need specific allocation for very specific cases (stack allocation, pooling) you have to make your code extensible using a custom allocator that user can change (easy if user can access and recompile your source code, else you have to provide some sort of interface).

Note that STL containers uses custom allocators so you can improve/degreade their performance by just changin the allocator:

**C++11 way:**

```
namespace myspace{
    template< typename T>
    using myVector = std::vector<T, yourAllocator<T>>;
}

//usage
myspace::myVector vec;
```

**Old way:**

```
namespace myspace{
    template<typename T>
    struct myVector{
        typedef std::vector<T, yourAllocator<T>> type;
    };
}

//usage
myspace::myVector::type vec;
```

If you really wish to override global new/delete all you need is to compile your own version of new/delete (of course you have to use some **malloc/malloc library**) and link that into your executable as last (well I think order doesn't matter, unless someone else override those operators too).

**Problems:**

On Windows you cannot override global new/delete for DLLs for wich you can't control linking. **Go back and read again**. If you cannot recompile/relink a DLL you cannot override its memory allocation that means you have to take care when using a DLL. Generally that's not a problem, unless you try to delete something created by a DLL using your own delete. For system DLLS that's not a problem (you can create objects/handles only using system functions and you can destroy objects/handles only using system functions)

I just ask you a question and I'll let you find an answer:
If you have a class, that class is compiled into a DLL (on Windows) do you really have to warry if you create a subclass with your custom new/delete and then you create a custom instance of that class?

```
class DLLEXPORT AClass{
//stuff
//...
};
```

your code

```
class MyClass: public AClass{

};
```

or

```
class MyClass: public virtual AClass{

};
```

.

```
//inside your program
AClass * a = new AClass;
MyClass * m = new MyClass;
```